# What is the difference between 'LBA' and 'non-LBA' IDs in an MBR partition table?

Tags: partitioning, mbr

In an MBR partition table, each partition entry contains a one-byte identifier that is supposed to describe what kind of file system is contained in the partition. The FAT family of file systems has been issued multiple such IDs, one for each width of a FAT entry. Curiously though, each FAT variant other than FAT12 and the type for extended boot record also has an additional ID for an 'LBA' variant of the file system:

| ID (non-LBA) | ID (LBA) | File system |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0x01` | none | FAT12 |
| `0x04`, `0x06` | `0x0e` | FAT16 |
| `0x0b` | `0x0c` | FAT32 |
| `0x0f` | `0x05` | Extended boot record |

Modern OSes are usually able to determine on their own how a drive is supposed to be addressed. Even back when LBA addressing was young, and disks were accessed via the BIOS, it should have been possible to simply probe for the availability of the appropriate interrupt 13h calls and fall back to the CHS version if they are absent. The additional partition IDs therefore seem redundant.

What was then the significance of those additional partition IDs? Did they influence the disk format, the file system drivers or boot code in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JdeBP’s answer is correct, but incomplete. The primary purpose of partition type ID is indeed to hide partitions from older operating systems (which mostly means older versions of DOS) which would be unable to access the partition correctly. Sometimes this was because of arbitrary size limitations of the disk driver; in others, this because of a change to the FAT disk format itself (wider FAT entries, change in BPB structure).

The complete table (adapted from [KB Q69912](https://archive.ph/Kipf)) should look like this:

| Type | DOS version | File system | Addressing | Size limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0x01` | ≥ 2.0 | FAT ≤12 | CHS | ≤ 16 MiB (32768 sectors) |
| `0x04` | ≥ 3.0 | FAT ≤16 | CHS | ≤ 32 MiB (65536 sectors) |
| `0x05` | ≥ 3.30 | EBR | CHS | (≤ 8032.5 MiB ***) |
| `0x06` | ≥ 4.0 | FAT ≤16 | CHS | (≤ 8032.5 MiB ***) |
| `0x0b` | ≥ 7.10 ** | FAT ≤32 | CHS | (≤ 8032.5 MiB ***) |
| `0x0c` | ≥ 7.10 ** | FAT ≤32 | LBA | (≤ 2 TiB ***) |
| `0x0e` | ≥ 7.0 * | FAT ≤16 | LBA | (≤ ~2 GiB ****) |
| `0x0f` | ≥ 7.0 * | EBR | LBA | (≤ 2 GiB *****) |

Read it as follows: if **all** the constraints in the last three columns are met (the whole partition is addressable with the given scheme, the partition is no larger and the FAT version is no later than specified), then one **may** use the type ID in the first column to expose the partition to DOS versions in the second column. There is no implication the other way: a CHS-addressable FAT12 partition with fewer than 32768 sectors may very well be identified as `0x0c`; it is just less useful to do so.

All DOS versions are also under the constraint that cluster size cannot be larger than 64 sectors = 32768 bytes. If that assumption is broken, the best type to use is probably `0x07`.

DOS 7.0 and later use the partition type ID in another way: to choose which BIOS service to use to access the drive. As the names imply, CHS-addressed partitions are accessed through old INT 0x13 services (AH=0x02, AH=0x03), while LBA-addressed partitions are accessed via INT 0x13 extensions (AH=0x42, AH=0x43). The CHS driver is also subject to certain quirks and limitations, none of which apply to the LBA driver:

- If a CHS-addressed partition begins on sector (0, 0, 1), i.e. it overlaps the MBR sector, DOS will recognise it, but will not be able to access it.
- CHS-addressed Extended Boot Records (of type `0x05`) must be aligned at a cylinder boundary; otherwise DOS will miscompute where the partition is located.
- CHS-addressed Extended Boot Records must not contain LBA-addressed logical drives.
- For logical drives contained in a CHS-addressed EBR, the partition offset stored in the BIOS Parameter Block (the so-called ‘hidden sectors’ field) is computed relative to its containing Extended Boot Record, instead of being disk-absolute.

---

* The DOS version first distributed with Windows 95 (4.0.950)

** The DOS version first distributed with Windows 95 OSR2 (4.0.1111)

*** Limitation imposed by the addressing scheme of the partition table (and data structures like the BPB): CHS can address at most 1024 × 255 × 63 sectors, LBA can address 2<sup>32</sup> sectors. (The KB article claims a limit of 1024 × 255 × 64, but this is likely erroneous.)

**** Limitation imposed by maximum cluster size of 64 sectors; 512 bytes per sector × 64 sectors per cluster × 65525 clusters ≈ 2 GiB in the FAT cluster area. Theoretically, even with this constraint this limit could be broken with a large reserved sector area or root directory area, but other size limitations may remain.

***** Source of this constraint is unclear; perhaps it is spurious.

Comment: Bugfix for DOS unable to access (0,0,1): https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20308/why-can-ms-dos-not-read-partitions-starting-at-logical-sector-0?rq=1

Comment: I believe the LBA you refer to, the BIOS extended INT 13h access method, not to be confused with LBA on IDE hard drives, is limited to addressing 2^64 not 2^32 sectors. The  only 2TiB (2^32) storage limit I know of, excluding filesystems, is found in the 32-bit offset fields in the DOS MBR or partition table.

Comment: @AlexCannon Yes, the MBR limit is what I was referring to. I have tested DOS to work fine with partitions located above the 2 TiB mark (in a VM image, obviously), so it’s not a matter of the client of the disk interrupt services being limited to 32 bits; however, all data structures holding the total number of sectors in the volume (MBR, BPB, etc.) are limited to 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

They are there to stop the (old) operating systems that *do not use LBA I/O* from trying, and failing, to access these partitions.  Partition types control which operating systems try to look at what is in a partition.  Operating systems that use LBA I/O know to look at partitions with the newer partition types.  Operating systems that do not treat the partitions as stuff that they should ignore.

The same went for (old) operating systems that could not cope with partitions being larger than 16MiB, and then 32MiB.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). "[How partition types (do not) imply filesystem types](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/determining-filesystem-type.html#PartitionTypes)".  *How to determine the filesystem type of a volume*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll accept this one. Though what actually prompted me to ask this question was that I noticed that the 'hidden sectors' field in the BPB seemed to be filled differently for 'LBA' and 'non-LBA' extended FAT partitions. The [article on BPBs](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/bios-parameter-block.html) on your site seems to only mention extended partitions in passing.